# Get Wordpress User Information Using Variables

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the user email for a user by using their username. The information should be for the user whose profile is being viewed, not for the user that's currently logged in.

I tried the code below, but it's not working for me (it's giving me an undefined function error):

```
$userdata = get_data_by( 'user_nicename' , $rusername );
     if ( !$userdata )
     $rusermail = $userdata->user_email;
```

Is there any way to get the user's email address from the database with the username that doesn't rely on a string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Use [get_user_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) instead.**

[get_data_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/get_data_by/) is a function of the WP_User class, so you can only use it if you've already got a user object (eg. `$user->get_data_by()`).

In your case you don't have the user object *until* you've called this function.

Your updated code would look like:

```
$userdata = get_user_by( 'user_nicename' , $rusername );
if ( $userdata )
  $rusermail = $userdata->user_email;
```

Note I've also made an extra change here: `if ( $userdata )` rather than `if ( !$userdata )`. With the exclamation mark, your code to set the e-mail never would have run because you were basically saying *if there's no user, set the e-mail*.

*Additional note:* I'm unable to test right now, but some references say to use `'slug'` instead of `'user_nicename'`, so give that a go if the latter doesn't work.

Comment: @TimMalone I'm not getting an error. It's just not pulling anything, so I'm getting an empty link.

Comment: @SyrupandSass Did you try it with both `'slug'` and `'user_nicename'`?

Comment: Yep. I even tried using an if-else statement, and it just gives me the 'else' results.

Comment: @SyrupandSass You might need to do a little more debugging then - check what the value of `$rusername` is, make sure it exactly matches a `user_nicename` in the database, etc. I just reviewed the [WP_User class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/) and I'm 99% sure it should work...

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd recommend a `var_dump($userdata)` right BEFORE the `if` statement, just AFTER the `$userdata = get_user_by(...)` statement

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer today. Or, this is what finally worked for me:

```
global $wpdb;
          $mytable     = $wpdb->prefix . "table_name";
          $mylink = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $mytable WHERE user_login = '$rusername'" );
          $sender = get_user_by( 'ID', $mylink->ID ); 
          $rusermail = $sender->user_email;
```